# Can I get the actual number of pages in Excel via Applescript?

Tags: excel, applescript

I know one can use the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method with the `GET.DOCUMENT(50)` macro sheet function to return the total number of pages that will be printed on a  worksheet.

Is something like that possible at all in AppleScript?

Comment: Why the double question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145471/is-there-an-equivalent-to-executeexcel4macro-in-applescript

Comment: One is general "how can I get the pages" and the other is just "how can I do "ExecuteExcel4Macro" - I was trying to avoid the XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly.

You can create a macro in your sheet and run it via Applescript.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  open "yourSheet.xls"
  run VB macro "yourMacro"
end tell
```

If you need to access the number in your Applescript, you'll probably need your macro to print the number somewhere in your document and read it with your Applescript.

EDIT: Per your comment I am afraid you'll need something that starts like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Microsoft Excel"
    click menu item "Macros..." of menu 1 of menu item "Macro" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Tools" of menu bar 1
  end tell
end tell

delay 1

tell application "System Events"
   keystroke "abc"
   keystroke {return}
end tell

..then you paste your macro, save it, run it..
```

Comment: I want to avoid creating the macro externally - I'd like to have everything contained in a single applescript file instead, to avoid dependencies, multiple files etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the `page setup object` object there are two properties

- `fit to pages tall`
- `fit to pages wide`

---

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell page setup object of sheet 1
        set pagesTall to fit to pages tall
        set pagesWide to fit to pages wide
    end tell
end tell
```